# jq - return true when key is not present

Tags: json, jq

I have a test that uses jq results and returns **"true"** when a key name does ***not*** exist in my json and **false** when it does

Specifically I have JSON like this ( first example)

```json
{
  "control": "library_blacklist",
  "policy_id": 13,
  "policy_name": "the-policy"
}
```

However when a blacklisted library is found then the output looks like this (second example)

```json
{
  "blacklisted_library_found": [
    "library.dll"
  ],
  "control": "library_blacklist",
  "failed": true,
  "policy_id": 13,
  "policy_name": "the-policy"
}
```

So I need a jq query that will resolve to true in the first example where key "blacklisted_library_found" is *not* present and false in the second example where key blacklisted_library_found *is* present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `has` to check for the presence of that key, in combination with `not` to invert the result:

```bash
jq 'has("blacklisted_library_found") | not'
```

This produces `true` for the first example, and `false` for the second.
[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ga6w0rSrFci)